# Query returns the same data for 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am getting the same value for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd. Then the next line gives me the results supposed to be in the 2nd column supposed in the first row.

```
<?php  
 require "db.php"; 
 $sql = "select n_name, shortcut, IF(rank = 1>2, 2, shortcut) AS 1st, IF(rank = 1<2, shortcut, shortcut) AS 2nd, 
 IF(rank = 3=3, 1, shortcut) as 3rd from team inner join nonsport on team.n_id = nonsport.n_id";                         

 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("n_name"=>$row[0],"1st"=>$row[1], 
"2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[3]));

} 
echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

My expected output is

Example. Shortcut has a, b, c and they have rank a =1 b =2 c =3;

Then 1st = a, 2nd = b, 3rd = c;

What im getting is

1st = a, 2nd = a, 3rd = a;

then the next line shows

1st = b, 2nd = b, 3rd = b;

Comment: `rank = 1<2` ?? what is this intended to do?

Comment: i just tried that sir

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(rank = 1 > 2, 2, shortcut)
```

It solves as follows:

- If `rank` equals 1 then `rank = 1` is 1 else 0
- Can either 0 or 1 be greater than 2? No.
- So, `rank = 1 > 2` resolves always to false and output of `IF` will be thirst parameter i.e. shortcut.

---

```
IF(rank = 1 < 2, shortcut, shortcut)
```

This one returns shortcut always as 2nd and 3rd param both are shortcut.

---

```
IF(rank = 3 = 3, 1, shortcut)
```

In this,

- If rank is 3 then `rank = 3` is 1 else 0.
- Can `rank = 3` (output 0 or 1) be equal to 3? No.
- So, `rank = 3 = 3` always return false, and thus output is always the 3rd parameter i.e. shortcut.

Hence why all the three functions return the same value.

Regarding your expected output, please edit your question to add sample data and expected output based on it along with complete explanation of the logic.

Comment: Oh thats how the if else query work in php? I didnt know that. I just put random things there and hope to get the answer. Thanks

Comment: @orange uhmm that's not PHP.

Comment: Wtf haha in really lost. Thanks again